# Gurobi stopping criteria in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, iteration, gurobi

I have been trying to write a MILP in Matlab. I am using gurobi solver interfaced with Matlab.

It seems solver has found a heuristic optimal solution but does not stop the iterations and keep looking for it. I am posting the screenshot of the process.

[image]

Can anyone tell me, how to write a stopping criteria of gurobi in Matlab? I've tried to look through the documentation of gurobi, but it didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Gurobi may have found the optimal solution very quickly, it does not know yet it is optimal. Only after the gap % has become zero we are sure there are no better integer solutions. You can set a gap tolerance (parameter `mipgap`), but for proven optimal solutions you need to leave it at (close to) zero.